# Comparação de Numeros javascript

Tags: javascript

Iniciando um rascunho para cobrança do estacionamento preciso saber a melhor forma de calcular os valores com base na quantidade de minutos.
Dessa forma não esta funcionando, acredito ter erros nos operadores lógicos (não sou familiarizado com Javascript)

```
var valor_total = 0.00;

if(tempo_considerado <= 0){
valor_total = 0.00;}
if(tempo_considerado > 0 <= 10){
valor_total = 0.00;}
if(tempo_considerado > 10 <= 15){
valor_total = 2.50;}
if(tempo_considerado > 15 <= 30){
valor_total = 4.00;}
if(tempo_considerado > 30 <= 45){
valor_total = 5.00;}
if(tempo_considerado > 45 <= 60){
valor_total = 6.00;}
if(tempo_considerado > 60){
valor_total = 10.00;}

valor_total = Math.floor(valor_total).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Nãu seria assim if(tempo_considerado > 0 && tempo_considerado  <= 10)

Comment: o `tempo considerado` não foi considerado, ou seja, não foi declarado :)

Comment: Na verdade a variável tempo_considerado vem de um bloco de código anterior

Comment: há quam acha que usuários do StackOverflow têm poderes mágicos telepáticos e são capazes de adivinhar com exatidão o que é que está acontecendo no ambiente de quem pergunta. Acreditam que esses seres  dotados de superpoderes podem adivinhar qual é o código  e todas as outras informações necessárias sem precisar ver nada sobre isso e ainda são capazes de descobrir o que há de errado nisso tudo. Dessa forma, esses usuários acreditam que não é necessário colocar essas informações no texto da pergunta pois elas podem ser obtidas por quem responde através de meios sobrenaturais e paranormais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não pecisa fazer a comparação AND. Neste caso você pode usar else. ficaria

```
if(tempo_considerado <= 0){
    valor_total = 0.00;}
else if(tempo_considerado<= 10){
   valor_total = 0.00;}
else if(tempo_considerado<= 15){
   valor_total = 2.50;}
else if(tempo_considerado<= 30){
  valor_total = 4.00;} 
else if(tempo_considerado<= 45){
  valor_total = 5.00;} 
else if(tempo_considerado<= 60){
  valor_total = 6.00;}
else if(tempo_considerado > 60){
  valor_total = 10.00;}
```

Answer (score 4):

Bom faltou o operador logico AND(&&) ou OR(||), e no código não esta declarando o  `tempo_considerado`

```js
function myfuction(){
 var valor_total = 0.00;
 var tempo_considerado = document.getElementById("tempo").value;
 if(tempo_considerado <= 0){
    valor_total = 0.00;}
 if(tempo_considerado > 0 && tempo_considerado<= 10){
   valor_total = 0.00;}
 if(tempo_considerado > 10 && tempo_considerado<= 15){
   valor_total = 2.50;}
 if(tempo_considerado > 15 && tempo_considerado<= 30){
  valor_total = 4.00;}
 if(tempo_considerado > 30 && tempo_considerado<= 45){
  valor_total = 5.00;}
 if(tempo_considerado > 45 && tempo_considerado<= 60){
  valor_total = 6.00;}
 if(tempo_considerado > 60){
  valor_total = 10.00;}

 valor_total = Math.floor(valor_total).toFixed(2);
 alert(valor_total);
}
```

```html
<input type="text"  id="tempo"/>
<input type="button" onclick="myfuction();" value="ok"/>
```

Comment: Na verdade a variável tempo_considerado vem de outro bloco de código anteriormente.  Mas entendi legal sua explicação

Comment: @EzequielTavares desculpa essa informação não tinha então não pude adivinha, mas funcionou ?

Comment: Vim no mercado quando chegar em casa testo. Mas eu acho que devo colocar breaks nos if's

Comment: Bom ai eu não sei te informa eu usaria 'else if', porém falar que é a melhor forma não sou a pessoa indicada

Answer (score 2):

Esqueceu de por o operador lógico nos ifs com duas cláusulas!
Seria:

```
if(tempo_considerado > 0 && tempo_considerado <= 10) //caso queira que o tempo seja maior que zero E menor ou igual a 10
```

ou

```
if(tempo_considerado > 0 || tempo_considerado <= 10) //caso queira que o tempo seja maior que zero OU menor ou igual a 10.
```